# Sorting list of data for Svelte components?

Tags: svelte, svelte-component

I'm having a slight issue with the usage of Svelte components and data consistency.

I have a list of companies that is initialised with a name from an array. I'm adding some component-specific variables, because I want to keep some intermediate states before saving.

The main (app.svelte) component holds the array of companies and also the button for sorting the list.

When I try to sort the list, the list is sorted just fine, but the component specific variables does not follow.

I've created a small example at https://svelte.dev/repl/ab5dc97a775c4ff48d3527646d913794?version=3.53.1 and as you can see, the age is not sorted with the name, when changing sort order.

I was thinking of storing all info in a Store, but it feels like a clumsy solution and defies the purpose of splitting the app into components (I could just use a big array in the app.svelte if I wanted to).

How can I fix my issue? - Or am I trying to do something impossible here?

Comment: Your question should also contain the code shown in the REPL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a key to your `#each` block so that the sorting works as expected [docs](https://svelte.dev/docs#template-syntax-each) - [tutorial](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/keyed-each-blocks)

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/6031d684d2324a13b9f79a0712356c69?version=3.53.1)

###### App.svelte

```
<script>
    import Greeting from './Greeting.svelte'

    let nameStore = [
        {
            'name': 'Hello', 
        },
        {
            'name':'world',
        },      
    ];

    function sortNameStore(multiplier) {
        nameStore.sort((a,b) => { 
            if (a.name > b.name) {
                return 1 * multiplier;
            }
            if (a.name < b.name) {
                return -1 * multiplier;
            } 
            return 0;
        })
        nameStore = nameStore; // Refresh data
    }
</script>

<div>
    {#each nameStore as item (item)}
    <Greeting item={item}/>
    {/each}

    <button on:click={() => {sortNameStore(1)}}>
        Sort by name LOW to HIGH
    </button>
    <button on:click={() => {sortNameStore(-1)}}>
        Sort by name HIGH to LOW
    </button>

</div>
```

###### Greeting.svelte

```
<script>
    export let item;
    let age = Math.random() * 60;
</script>

<div>
    Name: {item.name}, age = {age}<br>
</div>
```

`nameStore` doesn't have to be a store if only in the scope of `App.svelte` in this case.

Notice the section from the docs

> You can use any object as the key, as Svelte uses a Map internally — in other words you could do (thing) instead of (thing.id). Using a **string or number is generally safer, however**, since it means identity persists without referential equality, for example when updating with fresh data from an API server.

Concerning the sorting of strings you might want to have a look at [String.prototype.localeCompare()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare?retiredLocale=de)